# amixer doesn't allow me to control speaker and headphones separately

Tags: arch-linux, alsa

So, I'm using alsa-utils to control sound in my arch. Before, I had an opportunity to mute Speakers and unmute Headphones, but know, amixer shows only one option: Master, and no sound is going through headphones. 
Here is the result of "amixer":

```
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 65536
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch cswitch-joined
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 65536
  Front Left: Capture 16462 [25%] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 16462 [25%] [on]
```

When I try to change anything in alsamixer, it doesn't have any effect
[image: As you can see, i tried to mute the Speaker and unmute Headphones, but volume is still 0%]

My question is, do you have any ideas, how to return the capability to control these two outputs separately, not with Master?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Before"? What did you change?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know the exact moment when the situation changed. So I don't know what caused this change.

Comment: Your headphone is muted, select it and hit M

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Thkyiqw.png
It hasn't changed anything. In addition, I checked that if I mute Speaker, I simultaneously mute Master.

Answer (score 1):

When PulseAudio is enabled, it becomes the "default" sound device.

To select another sound card, use amixer's `--card` option:

```
amixer -c 0
```

Comment: I used this prompt. But with "amixer -c 1". It showed me all options of PCH - card, including Speaker and Headphones, but when I use "amixer" again to see the list of options, it shows only Master and Capture again.

Comment: This options affects only that single execution of `amixer`.